# Question body bug

Tags: support

I thought this was just a fluke, but it's happened about 10 times in the last few months, so I thought I'd report it as a bug.

Sometimes, the body of a question gets a grey background type thing, see screenshot:

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out what causes it to happen...

Comment: do you have any userscripts or style extensions active?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Nope

Comment: May be due to the edit made.... I mean that maybe whenever an edit is made and the page hasn't been updated with it the background turns grey...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, you have keyboard shortcuts enabled: check the [preferences page](https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/518562) of your user profile.

The grey background matches what happens when one presses a key that moves the shortcut focus on the post, for example `j` has this effect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct :) This is the highlighting for the keyboard shortcut for selecting posts.

Comment: Bingo, that was it :)